# setting up Marble to work with Qt

Tags: qt, marble

I am trying to set up [Marble](https://marble.kde.org/) to work with Qt 5.5 on OSX. I'm not very experienced with the details of linking and such and I think that is causing the problem I am having.

**Question:** Did I screw up the 'marble` install or is this an easily solved linking issue?

Qt 5.5 is installed in my user directory (using Qt's network installer) on a system running OSX 10.9.5. It works fine. I followed the [instructions](https://marble.kde.org/sources.php) on the Marble site to clone, build and install from source with (I believe) the appropriate Qt flags. That seemed to go without issue. When I try to build the simple test app listed [here](https://marble.kde.org/dev-intro.php), the `#include <marble/MarbleWidget.h>` line gives a "file not found" error.

After the install I've ended up with the following:

A "marble" directory in my root user folder

[image]

A "Marble.app" file along with various other `marble` related files in the bin and include directories. However the Marble.app gives the following error on launch:

> Dyld Error Message:   Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/Marble.app/Contents/MacOS/marble-qt   Reason: image not
>   found
>
> Binary Images:
>       0x7fff6a1f9000 -     0x7fff6a22c817  dyld (239.4) <7AD43B9B-5CEA-3C7E-9836-A06909F9CA56> /usr/lib/dyld

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a semi-solution: I used the Qt Creator "add Library" function and ended up with the following additions to the .pro file. I had to paste in the link to the lib since the dialog doesn't allow browsing of "usr/local/". Also, although I tried to link to the lib alias ("libmarblewidget-qt5.dylib"), the actual lib name is used.

```
macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lmarblewidget-qt5.0.21.80

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/local/include
```

I don't understand what this `$$PWD/../../../../../` business is.

But it worked and I am able to run the example code at the link in my question.

I wish this install/build stuff wasn't so damned arcane. I've spent endless hours just trying to get things set up – really sucks the joy out of exploring this stuff and I can't say I really learned much of anything from it.

---

**Update**

So I cleaned out the "$$PWD" crap and the literal lib name and it works. Not sure what difference it makes – but there you go.

```
macx: LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lmarblewidget-qt5

INCLUDEPATH +=/usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH +=/usr/local/include
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the build is faulty or you need a different version of Qt installed to run it. Usually the app has the Qt libraries that it needs wrapped up in the app itself. If it's not in there it will search your mac for it. The message says that QtCore can't be found in either place. If you look inside Google's Google Earth, you can see where the libraries are stored. You can also copy a version of QtCore into your Marble to see if it will work.